# PHP & regexp: перевод строки в массив

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

День добрый, господа знатоки!

Есть у меня блок-див, с классом `b-cat-marker js-schedule`. У него есть атрибут `data-ch`, который содержит необходимую мне информацию, выглядит так:

```
<div class="b-cat-market js-schedule" data-ch="{"49":{"id":"49","title":"Первый канал - Евразия","logo":{"width":"38","height":"30","src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333708610295M22586\/orig"}},"785":{"id":"785","title":"КТК","logo":{"width":"38","height":"30","src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333712749673M29386\/orig"}},"528":{"id":"528","title":"Астана","logo":{"width":"38","height":"30","src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333708111007M36576\/orig"}},"490":{"id":"490","title":"Седьмой канал","logo":{"...ndex.net\/get-tv-channel-logos\/1336217773495M65560\/orig"}},"614":{"id":"614","title":"Кухня ТВ","logo":{"width":"38","height":"30","src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333708867834M98854\/orig"}},"153":{"id":"153","title":"Авто Плюс","logo":{"width":"38","height":"30","src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333715566443M50909\/orig"}},"250":{"id":"250","title":"365","logo":{"width":"38","height":"30","src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333713180776M42789\/orig"}}}">
```

Как вы уже поняли, мне нужно каким-то чудом этот атрибут превратит в массив, например

```
$data["position"]=49;
$data["id"]=49;
$data["title"]=".....";
```

PS: нет опыта в регэксп.

Comment: это же json (правда невалидный).  при чем тут regexp?
нужно исправить его,  если он автоматически генерится, поправть генератор, отослать на сервер дальше преобразовать в массив.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[[@Yura Ivanov](/users/6117/yura-ivanov)](/users/6117/yura-ivanov) абсолютно прав - это json-представление данных. Если привести эти данные в удобочитаемый вид, то получим следующую картину:

```
{
    "49":{
        "id":"49",
        "title":"Первый канал - Евразия",
        "logo":{
            "width":"38",
            "height":"30",
            "src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333708610295M22586\/orig"
        }
    },
    "785":{
        "id":"785",
        "title":"КТК",
        "logo":{
            "width":"38",
            "height":"30",
            "src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333712749673M29386\/orig"
        }
    },
    "528":{
        "id":"528",
        "title":"Астана",
        "logo":{
            "width":"38",
            "height":"30",
            "src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333708111007M36576\/orig"
        }
    },
    "490":{
        "id":"490",
        "title":"Седьмой канал",
        "logo":{
            "...ndex.net\/get-tv-channel-logos\/1336217773495M65560\/orig" // (!!!) Смотрим на эту строку
        }
    },
    "614":{
        "id":"614",
        "title":"Кухня ТВ",
        "logo":{
            "width":"38",
            "height":"30",
            "src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333708867834M98854\/orig"
        }
    },
    "153":{
        "id":"153",
        "title":"Авто Плюс",
        "logo":{
            "width":"38",
            "height":"30",
            "src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333715566443M50909\/orig"
        }
    },
    "250":{
        "id":"250",
        "title":"365",
        "logo":{
            "width":"38",
            "height":"30",
            "src":"http:\/\/avatars.yandex.net\/get-tv-shows\/1333713180776M42789\/orig"
        }
    }
}
```

В строке, отмеченной комментарием, при генерации, явно допущена ошибка, а именно пропущен ключ **"src"**. Если мы ручками его допишем и поместим все данные в переменную, например **$str**, то уже не составит труда получить массив:

```
print_r(json_decode($str, true));
```

Что получиться в итоге, [можно посмотреть тут (перейти на закладку "Screen")](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/store/ex7-f3h)

Comment: @Deonis, большое спасибо за подробную инфу, открыл глаза. Я счастлив, ребята!.

Answer (score 1):

Если парсите что-то то:

```
preg_match_all('#data-ch="(.*)"#',$data,$matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $str){

     print_r(json_decode($str, true));

}
```

ну или иначе просто, как сказал [@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis), json_decode + валидность json